# Add website to Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure

We are currently in the process of building a website on azure. At this moment I have a cloud service that is hosting my web api. Deploying to azure works like a charm.

Besides this project we have a pure HTML AngularJS project. I can publish this website as a WebApp. Though, is it possible to deploy it together with the web api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy the second one as a Virtual Application/ Directory (Remember to check the Application check box):

[image]

You can use this link on how to publish to Root App as well as Virtual directory in your Azure subscription:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx

Comment: Can it be added to the same azure cloud service container?

Comment: They sure can. Your html app can live with your Api in the same app side by side...

Comment: Do you have any documentation how I can set it as a virutal application/directory? I cannot find it in any setting.